# Javascript display code when rectangle reaches somewhere

Tags: javascript

Code that should display alert when rectangle reaches somewhere; How much details you should add before question is displayed; The code uses popular javascript library. Vanilla javascript should have been good but it is difficult with that.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
  if(x==40 && y==40)
    {
    alert ("Hello world!");
    }
}
</script>   

<div id="draggable" onmousemove="showCoords(event)" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>  
</div>
function showAlert();
<p>Mouse over the rectangle above to get the horizontal and vertical coordinates of your mouse 
pointer.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_How much details you should add before question is displayed_" That much that we can understand what you need.

Comment: that sounds good

Comment: is it possible to draw rectangle with vanilla javascript ; for instance with javascript class cause now javascript has classes like other object oriented languages

Comment: Why draw a rectangle when you can position a `div`? In `showAlert()` you are using `x` and `y` where do those variables come from? Should they be the `#draggable`s coordinates? Maybe look at [jQuery.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: so bind to the drag event in the draggable

Comment: wow that just worked; Thanks Peter Krebs;

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
    at <anonymous> Why is that

Answer (score 1):

So use the events that draggable gives you. The event object has the position

```js
$("#draggable").draggable({
  start: function(evt){
    console.log("start", evt.clientX, evt.clientY, evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
  },
  drag: function(evt){
    console.log("drag", evt.clientX, evt.clientY, evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
  },
  stop: function(evt){
    console.log("stop", evt.clientX, evt.clientY, evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
  },
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thats useful for with console.log required was something that displays alert ehen it reaches somewhere;

Comment: So you add an if statement..... you already know how to do that in your example....

Comment: yes that sounds good is there any way could make rect stick when it reaches somewhere could show you js fiddle about what is being coded

Comment: @jvm_code that really is a different question.... I started work so I do not have time to make updates right now.

Comment: function ynof()
{
what.y=40;
}   should that move what when ynof() is called